# Bootstrap - activate navbar dropdown on hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

is there a way to activate the navbar so that the option drops down the items on hover and not on click? Thanks

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

You can use hover function;

```
    $(".nav .dropdown").hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gfy3Lfd0/)